# Flash rotating banner won't start playing in Firefox

Tags: .net, xml, flash, firefox

This issue has been boggling me a few days, I would appreciate any input.

[On this site](http://spectrumbridge.com/specex), the rotating flash banner at the top works fine in IE and Chrome, but when opened in Firefox, it doesn't load the picture or advance automatically. If you click on one of the other buttons to advance to another item, it works fine, but on page load, it will not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
AC_FL_RunContent(
'type', 'application/x-shockwave-flash',
'FlashVars', 'xmlUrl=/Images/SpecEx/banner.xml',
'width', '940px',
'height', '300px',
'movie', '/Shared/Flash/banner',
'wmode', 'transparent',
); </script>
```

I tried to put the 'play', 'true' option, but that doesn't help. I'm not sure why this is happening. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using [SWFobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) instead of AC_FL_RunContent() ?

In my experience, SWFobject runs better and it seems like more people use it. Maybe you should try it.

As for your code with AC_FL_RunContent(), it looks ok to me except that I would add the play option. But you say that it doesn't work so no use to try it again I guess. If you decide to try SWFobject, let me know if it works.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, I'm not sure how to do that on here. 
I tried to use swfobject, but I can't seem to get it to work. 
here's what I have


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var flashvars = { flashvars: "/Images/SpecEx/banner.xml" };
    
    swfobject.embedSWF("/Shared/Flash/banner.swf", "banner", "940", "300", "9.0.0","expressInstall.swf", flashvars);
</script>

It just shows a black box with a white loading circle. Any ideas?